# Inserting data in non related table - Symfony2 & Doctirne2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am building some business application and lets say there are two tables **`Orders`** and **`MonthlyReports`** . 
These tables are not directly related (there is no relationship between them defined in ORM).
Table `MonthlyReports` stores total amount of all orders and it should be updated after each purchase that is recorded in `Orders` table.

I planned to use `EventListener postPersist()` to automatically change the value of total amount in `MonthlyReports`, but I face this problem:

- Doctrine doesn't allow inserting new entities beside using persist() method, and `MonthlyReports` can't be persisted since it is not related to `Orders` table

So my question is how to create a new report at the beginning of each month, should I create some fake relationship between these tables to be able to persist new monthly report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MonthlyReports can't be persisted since it is not related to Orders table

Doctrine events aren't coupled to specific entities and their relationships. You can define a listener to do whatever you want.

```
<service id="your_namespace.entity.listener.monthly_report_recalculator" class="Your\NamespaceBundle\EventListener\MonthylReportRecalculator">
    <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="prePersist" method="prePersist" priority="80" />

    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
    </call>
</service>
```

Note, if your injecting repositories into an doctrine event listener, you unfortunately will have to grab it from the container if you want to avoid a cyclical dependency.

```
<?php

namespace Your\NamespaceBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MonthylReportRecalculator
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * Define Container
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntity();

        if ( ! $entity instanceof Order) {
            return;
        }

        // grab the report repository from container
        // update your report entity
        // save via repository
    }
}
```

I would also suggest you define a collection of Order entities within your Report entity for auditing purposes.

Comment: Ok, I have one question, let's say it's the first day of a month and I want to insert a new report on the fly. Doctrine manual says: _INSERT statements are not allowed in DQL, because entities and their relations have to be introduced into the persistence context through EntityManager#persist()_ http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#types-of-dql-queries . Having that in mind, I'm not sure how to insert new report using report repository.